# Как передать UserAgent в aiohttp ClientSession в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, aiohttp

*Пишу Telegram бота и мне необходимо передать UserAgent при отправке запроса, чтобы получить данные с сайта, иначе сайт не даст мне необходимые данные.*

*Код который есть у меня сейчас вы можете видеть внизу, здесь как-то надо передать UserAgent:*

```
async def request(text, x, text):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(f'http://example.com/{text}') as response:
            html_code = await response.text()
            await get_text(html_code, x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так можно:

```
user_agent = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36 OPR/72.0.3815.465 (Edition Yx GX)',
}

async def request(text, x, text):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(f'http://example.com/{text}', headers=user_agent) as response:
            html_code = await response.text()
            await get_text(html_code, x)
```